# Creating a widget with browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

I am doing *browserify-adventure* tutorial from nodeschool. One of the exercises involves creating a simple widget which turns an html string into DOM element, inserts a given name into it and then appends it to a selected target in the document. A solution which works looks like this:

```
var domify = require('domify');
var html = '<div>Hello <span class="name"></span>!</div>';

module.exports = Widget;

function Widget() {
    if (!(this instanceof Widget)) return new Widget;
    this.element = domify(html);

    this.setName = function(str) {
        this.element.querySelector("span.name").textContent=str;
    }

    this.appendTo = function(target) {
        target.appendChild(this.element);
    }
}
```

I understand how everything works in this script, except one thing - can someone enlighten me why this particular line is necessary for the widget to work?

```
if (!(this instanceof Widget)) return new Widget;
```

Without it, in the browser I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setName' of undefined
    at Object.3.shoe (bundle.js:2397)
    at s (bundle.js:1)
    at e (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
```